# Is there a library to fit a Threshold Autoregressive Model (TAR) in Python?

Tags: time-series, python, autoregressive

I tried to look into Statsmodel but I couldn't find it. I know that in R there is the TAR package. I would like to find something similar for Python.

My entire project is written in Python and I've never used R.

Comment: According to http://www.chadfulton.com/topics/setar_model_functionality.html this is currently in the statsmodel development branch, but has not yet been  pushed into the main branch. If you can install the development branch of statsmodel you should be ready to go. Based on my personal experience, the developer would be glad to help because you would be helping them test the development code before it hits the main code branch..